# UISwitch displays strangely when it is turned off (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The UISwitch displays strangely if the default value is on when the app is launched and I turn it off later. But it's normal the other way around. Why does it happen?

It is programmatically created in Objective-C and written inside viewDidLoad. It's on an ordinary view (login page), not on a reusable cell or something.

[Please see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S43a.png)

```
    saveUserSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((saveUserLb.frame.origin.x + 140),saveUserLb.frame.origin.y + 10, 40, 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:saveUserSwitch];

    if ([username isEqualToString: @""]) {
        self.saveUserSwitch.on = false;
        usernameFld.text = @"";
    } else {
        self.saveUserSwitch.on = true;
        usernameFld.text = username;
    }
```

Comment: Using the View Hierarchy Debugging https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html is there only one? Also, are you only testing in Simulator?

Comment: I test both on my phone and on simulator. I will try View Hierarchy Debugging!

Comment: There are some glitches when turning switch on or off inside UICollectionView ... so if you attach action post that code as well ... your code ... you use saveUserSwitch and self.saveUserSwitch ... are you sure they are the same? As Larme mention maybe there are two?

Comment: @P.H. - where is this code? You are almost certainly calling this twice (at least)... Here's what it looks like when a `UISwitch` in the **Off** state is overlaid on top of a `UISwitch` in the **On** state:     https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHNBD.png

Comment: Thanks, all! I used View Hierarchy Debugging to find out where those UI elements were loaded twice!